# WaitforMultipleObjects not work properly

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I try to monitor changes on

1. `//server/results`
2. `//server/results/1`
3. `//server/results/1/output`
4. `//server/results/2`
5. `//server/results/2/output`
6. `//server/results/3`
7. `//server/results/3/output`
8. etc...

Each of them has a handle created by `FindFirstChangeNotification`. Therefore when more results are generated, the number of handles are getting close to the server connection limit 50. (Normaly One single remote server can support max 50 receive functions at the same time.) My problem is that everything works fine until the number of handle reaches around 47, then `//server/results` stops working.

Comment: Code snippet? `WaitForMultipleObjects` works bulletproof with amount of handles up to `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`.

Comment: Very strange question. Title mentions `WaitForMultipleObjects` but then there is no mention in body of question. Without code this is a non-question. And `WaitForMultipleObjects` is known to work. Problem is in your code. You need to adjust your mindset here.

Comment: Why not just watch `//server/results` with `bWatchSubtree` set to true?

Comment: The second argument for this function is *bWatchSubtree*.  Clearly you want to use that so you limit the number of notifications you need.  Use ReadDirectoryChanges to be able to filter to a specific subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `FindFirstChangeNotification`, you could try using [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) instead, which can monitor a folder recursively.